# Optimization of speed in R

Tags: r, function, loops, optimization

I am currently working on a function that works on a big matrix of 2 columns ( number of values > 2000 in general) and have a time problem.

here the head of my matrix :
[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQRoC.png)

here my function :

```
get <- function()
{
  v <- sample(1:1e6,20000, replace=TRUE) #for example
  table <- #mymatrix
  for ( i in 1:nrow(table))
  {
    b <- which(v > table[i,1] & v < table[i,2]) #want index between 2 intervals
  }
  return(b)
}
```

the problem is the which it is too long when I repeat my loop for the whole table, and i can't find how to fix it (still learning in R).

Comment: First of all, you are rewriting your outcome variable `b` within the loop. Thus preserving only the values from the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

As Andrey said in a comment, you’re only returning the result for the last row. You’re also not passing `table` into the function (in fact, your function has *no* arguments), and it’s also unclear what `v` represents and in particular why it has more values than `table` has rows.

However, assuming that you want the results for all rows, you can do two things:

- Don’t use `which`, you probably don’t need numeric indices.
- Use vectorisation instead of a `for` loop:

```
get = function(table) {
  v = sample(1 : 1E6, 20000, replace = TRUE)
  v > table[, 1] & v < table[, 2]
}
```

That’s it.

Comment: Perhaps also change the function name to avoid confusion?

Comment: actually i need numeric indices

Comment: Im working on SNP data, and want to chose markers that are contain on segment portion that i have delimited from a previous file. This is why i need numeric indices. the "matrix i have provided is the matrix containing the segment delimitation for my chromosom, and "v" the marker for my chromosom

Comment: @Kratos From your description it’s not clear that you need numeric indices, sounds like logical indices should do just fine; you do realise that you can use this to subset a table, right? Using the above, `table2[get(table1), ]` does just what you’d expect. — At any rate, if you *really* need numeric indices, you can just call `which` on the result of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that would, for every value in vector `v` tell you which of the bins it fell into.

```
tbl = matrix(c(0,224,
               225,233,
               234,239,
               240,243,
               244,290,
               291,292),
             byrow = TRUE, 
             ncol = 2);

v = c(0,100,224,
      225, 230, 233,
      235)

fi1 = findInterval(v, tbl[,1]+1)
fi2 = findInterval(v, tbl[,2]-1)

set = (fi1!=fi2)
b = double(length(v))
b[set] = fi1[set];

# show the results
cbind(value = v, bin = b)

# value bin
# [1,]     0   0
# [2,]   100   1
# [3,]   224   0
# [4,]   225   0
# [5,]   230   2
# [6,]   233   0
# [7,]   235   3
```

Comment: On this site we also thank people by upvoting their answer and accepting it.